# How to move function names, comments, local variable names and structs to a database for a new version of the executable?

Tags: ida

I have reversed a number of functions and added definitions for some structs in an Intel x64 PE  executable. A program got an update. I moved old executable with the old database into another folder and I opened new executable and IDA created new database.

Now I'd like to move information I gathered in the old executable into the new database: function names, comments for specific assembly lines, defined structures, renamed offsets(in the assembly instruction ) to represent offets of structs, etc.

I googled it and found BinDiff plugin for IDA, and successfully ported function names and comments to the same executable(in a small VC++ test solution) opened in another folder with debugging symbols stripped.

But it didn't touch the defined structures. The reason I used a small test project is because when I tried it on a real IDB, it was taking IDA too long to BinDiff the databases: the IDBs are 1.4GB in size with 180k functions recognized by IDA. I left it for half an hour and then decided to try it on a small project.

So how to move all relevant information to the new database for the new version of the executable?

Comment: After googling more, I found: https://github.com/joxeankoret/diaphora . I'll try it, looks like it will just might be able to do what I'd like to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Diaphora](http://github.com/joxeankoret/diaphora) is the closest thing to what I'd like to have.

It doesn't port everything, though: doesn't port stack variables(arguments, local variables), which is a good enough and important enough chunk of reversing functions.

Comment: Have you found anything to migrate local variable, arguments as well as global names?